# Incorrect syntax near Go with Pypyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I am using the `pypyodbc` library to establish a connection to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database and every time I try to execute a .sql file I encounter the following error:

`pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Go'.")`

This is the sql query I am trying to execute:

```
Use SL_Site1_App
Go

select emp_num,name, trans_num, job, trans_type
from Hours where trans_type like '1000%'  order by trans_date desc
```

This is the python script that I am using:

```
import pypyodbc, ExcelFile

def main():
    # read the SQL queries externally
    queries = ['C:\\Temp\\Ready_to_use_queries\\Connection_sql_python.sql']

    for index, query in enumerate(queries):
        cursor = initiate_connection_db()
        results = retrieve_results_query(cursor, query)
        if index == 0:
            ExcelFile.write_to_workbook(results)
            print("The workbook has been created and data has been inserted.\n")

def initiate_connection_db():      
    connection_live_db = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="my-name",
                                      pwd="try-and-guess", Trusted_Connection="No")
    connection = connection_live_db.cursor()
    return connection
```

The workaround for this problem is to delete the `Use SL_Site1_App Go` line but I want to know if this is a known problem related to the pypyodbc library to process these lines and if so, where should I look to notify the developers about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` is a batch separator used by `sqlcmd` and SSMS. It's not a T-SQL operator.

Considering you're using an application to connect to SQL Server, declare your database in the connection string, by adding `database="SL_Site1_App"`, and then remove the `USE` and `GO` statements in your SQL Statement.